# Calculate automatically the distance in a range between two numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two numbers x and y and a range of month z. Example: I start with a value of 2 in the first month and after 17 month I get a value of of 1234. How can Excel calculate automatically the value of each month (15) between the two values?

[image]

Comment: A screenshot would be of great help!

Comment: This is unclear, you need to provide an example showing what you are meaning and what calculation you expect to take place.

Comment: I can't upload pictures because of my lack on rep. Posted the question here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20435624/calculate-missing-gaps-with-excel)

Answer (score 1):

http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excelformulas/ss/formula_begin.htm
Simply have excel calculate z/(x-y) by using the built in formula function, although this does assume all months have the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Plot your three points on a chart and try adding trend lines to see which suits your requirements best. The best fit of those available to me may be Polynomial of order two (though note that overshoots month 7 in earlier months). Select Display Equation on chart and it came up with:

```
y = -58.75x2 + 674x - 605.2
```

for me. Solving for all seven months gave me:

```
+---+---------+
| 1 |  10     |
| 2 |  508    |
| 3 |  888    |
| 4 |  1,151  |
| 5 |  1,296  |
| 6 |  1,324  |
| 7 |  1,234  |
+---+---------+
```

YMMV.